# How to pass Mapbox Access Token in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, mapbox, android-jetpack-compose, mapbox-android

I'm trying to add Mapbox to a Jetpack Compose project. The Documentation has no information about Jetpack Compose so I'm struggling with adding my Access Token to the Map instance.
I have added my Access Token as a string resource named `mapbox_access_token` as described in the [Docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/). But the Token doesn't get send to the request to fetch the styles I just get a `401` Error returned:

```
OnMapLoadError: STYLE, message: Failed to load style: HTTP status code 401, sourceID: null, tileID: null
```

This is my Composable to display a Map:

```
@Composable
fun MapboxMap() {
    val mapView = rememberMap(0.0, 0.0)
    val accessToken = stringResource(R.string.mapbox_access_token)

    AndroidView(
        factory = { mapView },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        update = {}
    )
}

@Composable
private fun rememberMap(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): MapView {
    val accessToken = stringResource(R.string.mapbox_access_token)
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val isDarkTheme = LocalDarkMode.current

    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply {
            val mapBoxMap = this.getMapboxMap()

            mapBoxMap.loadStyleUri(if (isDarkTheme) Style.DARK else Style.LIGHT)

            mapBoxMap.setCamera(
                cameraOptions = cameraOptions {
                    center(Point.fromLngLat(longitude, latitude))
                    zoom(6.0)
                }
            )
        }
    }

    return mapView
}
```

I store the `mapbox_access_token` in a file at this location: `res/values/mapbox_access_token.xml`. The [Docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/) say to store it inside a files called `R.strings.xml` might this cause MapBox to not find the my access token?

This is how my screen looks when I add my `MapboxMap` Composable. The map is not getting loaded because my access token is not sent with the request to get the style.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you did not initialize the map properly.

Here is almost minimal example that is at least working for me.

```
@Composable
fun MapExample(latitude: Double = 0.0, longitude: Double = 0.0) {
   val mapView = rememberMap(latitude, longitude)

   ConstraintLayout(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
   ) {
    val mapRef = createRef()

    AndroidView(
        factory = { mapView },
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(mapRef) {
                height = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            },
        update = {  }
    )
}
}

@Composable
fun rememberMap(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): MapView {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val mapView = remember {
        MapView(context).apply {
           val mapboxMap = this.getMapboxMap()

           mapboxMap.loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)

           mapboxMap.setCamera(
               cameraOptions = cameraOptions {
                   center(Point.fromLngLat(longitude, latitude))
                   zoom(6.0)
            }
        )
    }
}
return mapView
}
```

The second thing which might be the case is that you did not create and import your secret token, as can be seen [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#configure-credentials). Hope this helps. But main reason is that you probably just did not call

```
MapView(context).apply{
val mapboxMap = this.getMapboxMap()
mapboxMap.loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the styles are still not getting loaded. I have updated my question to include your code snippets and also an image showing how the screen looks when displaying the Map composable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add this code in your rememberMap function

```
Mapbox.getInstance(context, stringResource(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
```

this is your full code look like

```
@Composable
private fun rememberMap(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): MapView {
    // val accessToken = stringResource(R.string.mapbox_access_token)
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val isDarkTheme = LocalDarkMode.current

    val mapView = remember {
       Mapbox.getInstance(context, stringResource(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
       MapView(context).apply {
          val mapBoxMap = this.getMapboxMap()

          mapBoxMap.loadStyleUri(if (isDarkTheme) Style.DARK else Style.LIGHT)

          mapBoxMap.setCamera(
            cameraOptions = cameraOptions {
                center(Point.fromLngLat(longitude, latitude))
                zoom(6.0)
            }
         )
      }
   }

   return mapView
}
```

Comment: I have currently taken a pause from working on the mapbox project. When I come back to it I will try your solution out. Thanks in advance!